# Transferring extensions from one user to another in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, users

I have a simple problem and I'm sure the answer is simple but I can't find anything on it... I Have successfully exported & imported about 25-30 extensions onto a new computer using my development Google account.

What I want to do is create a new user for Chrome which only has about 10 extensions of those original 25-30 extensions that is for my personal browsing. Essentially I just want to sync my development account into my personal account and remove the extensions I don't need while doing personal browsing.

I am using Chrome 24 on Ubuntu.